# For loop using string.length()

Tags: c++, string, for-loop

Can someone help me understand why this loop isn't working? I am trying to do 2 things:

1. Loop through a string using mystring.length()
2. Find any 0's or 1's in the string

Both of these features are not working. For example, if I pass in a string of 123450 then a) It only loops once and b) Even though the first char is a 1, it returns "no, no, no"

```
bool recognizer(string s)
{
    string mystring = s;

    for (int i = 0; i < mystring.length(); i++) {
        if ((mystring[i] == 0) || (mystring[i] == 1))  {
            cout << "yes, yes, yes";
            return true;
        }
        else {
            cout << "no,no,no";
            return false;
        }
    }
    
}// end of recognizer
```

Comment: You may want to use a range based for loop instead. `for (const auto& ch : mystring) { if ( ch == '0' || ch == '1') { // rest of code here`

Comment: _`no,no,no`, Daniel San!_

Comment: OT: Better pass a string argument by const reference.

Comment: Copying it to `mystring` seems pointless too...

Comment: But I need to return "true" or "false" for each character in the string. How would I be able to do multiple returns if the bool function terminates after the first return?

Comment: @imtryingmybest You can return from a function only once. (Suppose you don't want to write a coroutine. ;-)

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you don't need the internal parentheses in `if ((mystring[i] == 0) || (mystring[i] == 1))`. `if (mystring[i] == 0 || mystring[i] == 1)` means exactly the same thing, and doesn't have those ((distracting redundant) parentheses).

Answer (score 6):

> It only loops once

That's because you `return` from the loop body.

> Even though the first char is a 1, it returns "no, no, no"

That's because you don't compare with `'0'` and `'1'` characters, but `0` and `1` integers.

---

Proposed version:

```
bool recognizer(const std::string& s)
{
  return std::any_of(s.begin(), s.end(), 
    [](char c){ return (c == '0' || c == '1'); });
}
```

or, in C++20:

```
bool recognizer(std::string_view s)
{
  return std::ranges::any_of(s, [](char c){ return (c == '0' || c == '1'); });
}
```

or, with regex:

```
bool recognizer(const std::string& s)
{
  return std::regex_match(s, "[01]");
}
```

Comment: `string_view`!!

Comment: Not sure that `any_of` overload works as-is. If you're looking for the ranges version then it's in `std::ranges`. Otherwise you'll still need `s.begin(), s.end()`. But it's nice to be able to pass a string literal (or other C-string) without constructing a `std::string` (which we can do since C++17 in actuality)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings You're right, again :)

Comment: It happens occasionally :P

Answer (score 4):

To loop more than once, remove the `return true;` - they return right away. Because you've promised to return `bool`, you still have to do that - but do it after the loop finishes if you want to look at all characters in the string.

To match against a character zero like you would have in a string of characters, try `'0'` and `'1'` instead of `0` and `1`.

Answer (score 2):

You have two errors.

You return on the first iteration when comparing `mystring[i]` with an `int`.
The comparision is also wrong. You shall compare with a `char`, not an `int`.

```
bool recognizer(string s)
{
    string mystring = s;

    for (int i = 0; i < mystring.length(); i++) {
        if ((mystring[i] == '0') || (mystring[i] == '1'))  {
            cout << "yes, yes, yes";
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}// end of recognizer
```